# Converting a Date from a String representation to a numerical representation and back again

Tags: java, database, datetime, derby

Are there any patterns or known ways of converting a date from a string representation to a numerical representation and vice versa?
Background:
I am using an Apache Derby database as the persistence for a Java program. I would like to do something like this:

```
Select * from MyTable where date_column > 20100914154503 order by date_column DESC
// 20100914154503 = 2010-09-14 15:45:03
```

My dates are stored in my java program I am using Joda Time ( https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) DateTime object.
Thanks

Comment: So you have a timestamp column in the database and you want to query against it with a string, or you have a string column in the database and you want the result to be a DateTime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly consider looking into how your database manages dates and time, since it can probably do what you need.  Remember that the date you have should be stored in a date field in the database table.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure what you're actually trying to do or why you need to use a string at all, but in general you should use a `PreparedStatement`. Then you can just set the date in the `PreparedStatement` using a `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
DateTime date = ...;
Connection conn = ...;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "Select * from MyTable where date_column > ? order by date_column DESC");
ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getMillis()));
```

Comment: Timestamp storage in a database is nice and efficient, and you won't be gaining anything by storing a timestamp in a number field